# Azure App Service losing connection periodically to on-premise SQL Database on Azure Virtual Network until App Restart

Tags: c#, database, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

We have a web app hosted on Azure, the app service has a Virtual Network connected in the networking tab with route all data disabled.  The Virtual Network Gateway is connected via a site-to-site connection to a Local Network Gateway, the connection works correctly and we can query the on-premise database through the web application.

[image: App Service VNet Configuration]

Connection string to On-Premise Database:

```
Data Source=192.168.xxx.xxx\\Name;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=User;Password=Password;Trusted_Connection=False;Connection Timeout=120;
```

Example code for query:

```
using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(AppSettings.DBConnection))
{
    try
    {
        if (dbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            await dbConnection.OpenAsync();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.table";

        using (var sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, dbConnection))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            // Custom retrieval from dt
            details.itemDetails = DBHelper.GetListOfObjects<ItemDetail>(dt);
            details.otherDetails = DBHelper.GetListOfObjects<OtherDetail>(dt);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Could not fetch Item Details{Environment.NewLine}{e.Message}");
    }
}
```

After a few days, we receive a connection error to the on-premise database [image: Error Message]

The only way to fix the connection is to restart the Azure App Service.  I am still able to query the database from the app service Kudu console, however the App Service gives this error until restarted.  I think it losing connection momentarily and then cannot reconnect.

The Local Network Gateway exists on North Central US servers while the Virtual Network Gateway exists on West US servers, could this be an issue for disconnects in the virtual network?

Answer (score 0):

> A network -related or instance specfic error occurred while
> establishing a connection to sql server.The server was not found or was not accessible.verfiy that the instance name is correct and sql server is configured to allow remote connection (provide: SQL Network interface, error26-error Locating server/instance specified)

This error usually occurs if the application is unable to establish a connection to the SQL Server. Network instability may be caused by the Local Network Gateway and the Virtual Network Gateway in various Azure regions. When data travel between regions, network outages, latency, or packet loss might happen.

- Configure the Local Network Gateway to the same region as the Virtual Network Gateway to reduce latency and improve connectivity.

Check the on-premises database server is configured to allow remote connections and firewall allow traffic from the Azure App Service to reach the database server.

***In SQL server -> right click, properties -> connection -> allow remote connections like below:***

[image]

Check whether you Enabled TCP/IP protocol and set a predefined port number (1433)

Open **SQL Server Configuration Manager**-> start -> Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager.

In TCP/IP In Protocol under properties -> `Enabled=Yes`.  In IP Addresses -> `TCP Port = 1433`

[image]

Click on *SQL Server Configuration Manage* check ***SQL browser*** is running if running, right click on properties and stop and ***select sql server***, right click on properties and ***restart*** .

[image]

Then refer this [blog](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/)  try to add `specific local port 1433`  -> allow the connection to specific the action and create a inbound rule on ***Windows Firewall with Advanced Security***

To connect the windows server using windows Authentication open Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio -> click on your server-> right click on SQL instance -> properties -> security -> Select SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode like below:

[image]

To know more in detail, refer this link:

[How to configure remote access and connect to a remote SQL Server instance with ApexSQL tools](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/)